# Ionic Framework create file using File API

Tags: angular, api, file, typescript, ionic-framework

I just want to create a file. But as it turns out, this is quite difficult. Also, the official documentation of Apache is for JavaScript. However, i would like to implement it TypeScript.Let's just say I want to create an "access.log" file. But I'm not sure where the best place for this file is.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ionic native [File API](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) and create file using [createFile](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/#createFile) function of the File API.

I would recommend storing "access.log" file in `cordova.file.dataDirectory` as it just one file and would guess it is for internal usage of app. As you have not mentioned specific usage of the file I would suggest you check out [Where To Store Files](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#where-to-store-files) section of cordova documentation ( The Ionic File API is just a wrapper around it, so the docs are same ).

Example code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

@Component({
    selector: 'demo-comp',
    templateUrl: 'demo-comp.component.html',
})
export class DemoCompComponent {
    constructor(private file: File) { }

    createAccessLogFileAndWrite(text: string) {
        this.file.checkFile(this.file.dataDirectory, 'access.log')
        .then(doesExist => {
            console.log("doesExist : " + doesExist);
            return this.writeToAccessLogFile(text);
        }).catch(err => {
            return this.file.createFile(this.file.dataDirectory, 'access.log', false)
                .then(FileEntry => this.writeToAccessLogFile(text))
                .catch(err => console.log('Couldn't create file));
        });
    }

    writeToAccessLogFile(text: string) {
        this.file.writeExistingFile(this.file.dataDirectory, 'access.log', text)
    }

    someEventFunc() {
      // This is an example usage of the above functions
      // This function is your code where you want to write to access.log file
      this.createAccessLogFileAndWrite("Hello World - someEventFunc was called");
    }
}
```

This is a demo you need to call `createAccessLogFileAndWrite` from your own function and pass the text you want to append to the file.

Let me know in the comments if you face any problems.

Comment: Can you give me a small example how to do it ? I have read, I would have to prepare the file system first. I am a bit confused by these documents. I'm not doing so much with TypeScript or Web in general.

Comment: It seems like its not working. I dont get any error msg but no file was created. Here's my code: https://paste.ee/p/SaIWU (ts)

Comment: sorry, my bad. it should have been ```writeExistingFile```, I have edit my code now, can u pls try again.

Comment: 14:24:14]  typescript: src/pages/home/home.ts, line: 27 
            Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. 

      L26:  if(!doesExist) {
      L27:      return this.file.createFile(this.file.dataDirectory, 'Datei.txt')
      L28:      .then(FileEntry => this.writeToFile(text))

[14:24:14]  typescript: src/pages/home/home.ts, line: 28 
            Property 'writeToFile' does not exist on type 'HomePage'.

Comment: L27:  return this.file.createFile(this.file.dataDirectory, 'Datei.txt')
      L28:  .then(FileEntry => this.writeToFile(text))
      L29:  .catch(err => console.log('Couldnt create file'));

[14:24:14]  typescript: src/pages/home/home.ts, line: 36 
            Property 'writeExistingFile' does not exist on type 'HomePage'. 

      L35:  writeToAccessLogFile(text: string) {
      L36:      this.writeExistingFile(this.file.dataDirectory, 'Datei.txt', text)

Comment: I deleted ```.file``` while pasting ```writeExistingFile``` - edited my answer to fix it, also there is no ```writeToFile``` function we are using ```writeToAccessLogFile```

Comment: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.: `if(!doesExist) {
    return this.file.createFile(this.file.dataDirectory, 'Datei.txt')
    .then(FileEntry => this.writeToAccessLogFile(text))`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it! But there is still a small problem. The adb logcat gives me this message: "Directory doesnt exist", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (56008)

Comment: ```checkFile``` is supposed to return a boolean according to documentation. But it doesn't seem to be doing so, I moved the code of creating file to ```catch``` and edited my ans.

Comment: Finaly, it works fine! Also, I now understand exactly how the documentation of Ionic works. Thank you again for your time :)